# WPF - Text in TextBox not Selectable?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a project that dynamically loads text into a Text Box control. The problem is that, for some reason, the text does not seem as if it can be selected. I do not understand why as I thought that, by default, the text in a Text Box was selectable. Why is this and how can I fix it? Here is my XAML:

```
 <Window x:Name="viewWindow" x:Class="Games_Database.View"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="View" Height="300" Width="600" Loaded="windowLoad" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="77*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="13*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="57*"/>           
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="550" Margin="21,5,21,10" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsManipulationEnabled="True">
        <TextBox x:Name="text" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="False" Height="Auto" Width="500" Grid.RowSpan="2" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Times New Roman" IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled="True" Text="" AutoWordSelection="True" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's beacause you have IsHitTestVisible property set to false. Setting this property to false means that control will not respond on any mouse events. However you are still able to enter the control by using tab.

Perhaps [this blog post](http://wpf.2000things.com/2012/10/30/679-setting-ishittestvisible-to-false-prevents-interaction-with-controls/) will make it more clear to you.

Comment: I upvoted you anyway, even though you were late on the draw. =P

Answer (score 5):

The text cannot be selected because you have `IsHitTestVisible="False"`.

If you remove that attribute, the text box will once again be able to respond to mouse clicks from the user. Note that, with your current code, you *can* get the cursor inside the text box by pressing the tab key.

Comment: Ahh, I was three mins late. I can only add this [link to make things more clear](http://wpf.2000things.com/2012/10/30/679-setting-ishittestvisible-to-false-prevents-interaction-with-controls/)

Comment: Thanks you both; I really appreciate it! :)